# Title not showing on my webite's tab but it does locally

Tags: html, tabs, title

The content of the title tag is not showing on the tap bar of my website (which displays the url instead), but it does locally (I tested on three browsers). I moved around HTML elements, still the same. I'm confused as to why.

Here's my website: https://www.lilaait.com which is hosted on GitHub btw. I've also used the mark up validation service but no errors was showed for the head section.

Any cue would be much appreciated.

````
<head>

<title>Lila Ait </> Web Developer</title>

  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-140386734-1"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-140386734-1');
  </script>


  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="Web Portfolio" content="">
  <meta name="Lila Ait" content="">

  <!-- Custom fonts for this theme -->
  <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- Theme CSS -->
  <link href="css/freelancer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/freelancer.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--Particles Background-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/particles.css">


  <!--Naviguation-->
  <!--Icons Buttons-->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.0/css/all.min.css'>

</head>
```
````

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I'm betting it's the `</>` in your `title` tag. Try using [the HTML safe versions](https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp) of `<` and `>`. That will make your title tag `<title>Lila Ait &lt;/&gt; Web Developer</title>`.</strike>

I dug a little bit more into how the page is being shown, and it looks like the HTML document you put together for the site isn't actually being rendered at lilaait.com. That site has an iframe linked to https://pandassi.github.io/website.github.io/index.html, along with its own `title` tag just reading "lilaait.com".

You may need to revisit how you're putting your website on that custom domain. I'm not sure how much more help I can be without knowing more about how you're linking that github site to the domain name.

Comment: I removed </> altogether and still not showing up :-/